# Jmeter: Script not running for csv data

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

I made one script which has login Id, password, branch name and branch code.
I make csv for 10 user including all these value id, password ,branch name, and code.

I have done csv config setting properly. Problem is my script not taking csv value and running for only those value which are captured during recording. Recorded value not getting replace by csv value. My application is asp.net based. does the problem with application database or with my script?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you recorded the script but didn't change the values you are talking about to variables that you want to use in tests. So if you run 10 threads for 10 users from csv file you should use in the steps that you used those values for variable names.

So if in CSV Data Set Config you set Variable Names to something like id,password,branch_name,code, then in requests where you send that data you should change the values that were recorded to ${id}, ${password} and so on. So if you set the csv config properly values will be provided one by one for each thread.